# Algorithms/Data-Structures to calculate transitive call graphs in the presence of virtual dispatch?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, programming-languages, search-algorithms, compilers

## Algorithms/Data-Structures to calculate transitive call graphs in the presence of virtual dispatch?

I am trying to write a program to analyze Java programs and figure out the
transitive closure of the callgraph of each main method. Consider the program
below:

```java
class Foo{
    void runOne();
    void runTwo();
}
class Bar extends Foo{
    void runOne(){ }
    void runTwo(){ }
}
class Qux extends Foo{
    void runOne(){ }
    void runTwo(){ }
}

class MainA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bar().runOne();
    }
}
class MainB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Qux().runTwo();
    }
}
class MainC {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo[] foos = {new Bar(), new Qux()};
        for(Foo foo: foos){
            foo.runOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we would expect :

1. `MainA`'s transitive callgraph would include `Bar#runOne`
2. `MainB`'s transitive callgraph would include `Qux#runTwo`
3. `MainC`s transitive callgraph would include `Bar#runOne` and `Qux#runOne`

To get to that conclusion, we need to traverse the callgraph via two different
kinds of edges: each method can both call other methods, or it can instantiate
classes, and only if both a class is instantiated and a method is called do we
consider that method part of the callgraph.

Method calls and instance instantiations can appear in different places, e.g.

```java
class MainD {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        helperA(helperB());
    }
    public static void helperA(Foo foo){
        foo.runTwo();
    }
    public static Foo helperB(){
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

Here `helperA` calls `Foo#runTwo`, but we don't know what `Foo` is until
we get to `main` and we see that `helperB` instantiated a `new Bar()`, meaning
the transitive callgraph for`MainD.main` is `Bar#runTwo`. In fact, neither
`helperA` nor `helperB` would be enough to draw that conclusion on their own,
even though `MainD.main` which calls them is able to.

Effectively, it seems like we need to do a breadth/depth-first graph
traversal, with one kind of node representing each method definition, but two
kinds of edges: one representing method calls, and one representing class
instantiations. And we only add a node to our traversal if it has *both* kinds
of edges pointing to it.

For now, I'm ignoring the additional complexities of mutable state, exceptions,
reflection, and so on.

Is there a name for this kind of analysis/algorithm, or any prior art or
literature written up e.g. about its limitations or implementation strategies?
I can probably hack something together myself, but I'd rather build upon any
prior work that exists rather than having to re-discover it from first principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might be interested in Class Hierarchy Analysis (CHA), Rapid Type Analysis (RTA), or Variable Type Analysis (VTA).  These are three methods for efficient construction of a call graph in object-oriented languages like Java.  For instance, some of these algorithms are implemented in SOOT.

There is also other work on virtual method call resolution for Java, which you can search out using Google Scholar.  (For instance, you can use [points-to analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_analysis) for this purpose, e.g., Anderson's algorithm.)